# PySpark SQL - Loop through multiple variables in a single step

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with 200 million rows and 600 variables and I am trying to calculate the median for all variables. I need the median grouped by two class variables for each variable.

I am using PySpark 2.4.8.

I understand PySpark 3+ comes up median as a function built in so I could use it directly with .agg but this doesnt seem to be available in PySpark 2.4.8.

For the sake of simplicity, suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

sc = SparkContext()    

df = sc.parallelize([
    ['A', 1, 89, 6],
    ['A', 2, 90, 7],
    ['A', 3, 91, 8],
    ['B', 4, 100, 11],
    ['B', 5, 101, 13],
    ['B', 6, 102, 15],
]).toDF(('grp', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3'))

for c in df.columns:
      df.registerTempTable("df")
      median = sqlContext.sql(f"select grp, percentile_approx({c},0.5) as {c}_median from df group by grp")
      median.show()
```

This produces the output I expect, i.e.

```
+----+-----------+
| grp|var1_median|
+----+-----------+
|   A|          2|
|   B|          5|
+----+-----------+
+----+-----------+
| grp|var2_median|
+----+-----------+
|   A|        90 |
|   B|        101|
+----+-----------+
+----+-----------+
| grp|var3_median|
+----+-----------+
|   A|          7|
|   B|         13|
+----+-----------+
```

However, its very slow to run for 200 variables, presumably because its calling the whole dataset and calculating the median one variable at a time. Is there a way I can pass a single sql query such as
"select grp, percentile_approx(var1,0.5) as var1_median, percentile(var2,0.5) as var2_median......"
automatically so that it calculates the median of all variables in one step?

Answer (score 1):

This does the job.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)



df = sc.parallelize([
    ['A', 1, 89, 6],
    ['A', 2, 90, 7],
    ['A', 3, 91, 8],
    ['B', 4, 100, 11],
    ['B', 5, 101, 13],
    ['B', 6, 102, 15],]).toDF(('grp', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3'))

columns_list = list(df.columns)

print(columns_list)

for c in df.columns:
      df.registerTempTable("df")
      median = sqlContext.sql(f"select grp, percentile_approx({c},0.5) as {c}_median from df group by grp")
      median.show()

answer_df = df.groupBy(F.col(columns_list[0])).agg( *[F.percentile_approx(F.col(c),0.5).alias("median_"+c) for c in columns_list[1:]] )

print("answer_df dataframe")
answer_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+---+----------+
|grp|grp_median|
+---+----------+
|  B|      null|
|  A|      null|
+---+----------+

+---+-----------+
|grp|var1_median|
+---+-----------+
|  B|          5|
|  A|          2|
+---+-----------+

+---+-----------+
|grp|var2_median|
+---+-----------+
|  B|        101|
|  A|         90|
+---+-----------+

+---+-----------+
|grp|var3_median|
+---+-----------+
|  B|         13|
|  A|          7|
+---+-----------+

answer_df dataframe
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|grp|mediavar1|mediavar2|mediavar3|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|B  |5        |101      |13       |
|A  |2        |90       |7        |
+---+---------+---------+---------+
```